# Hover effect not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a few photos and I want on hover I want to cover them with `background: black;` I want to cover the whole image with black for example. The hover effect just doesn't appear. I suspect the problem is in the CSS selectors.
Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/20oomme4/3/

Comment: which part should be in black when hovered???

Comment: your images have a white background..so the black background wont be visible..

Comment: try adding a png image with transparent background.That should work for you..

Comment: i think you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/20oomme4/23/

Comment: Good suggestion...@Vitorino. I think he needs [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/20oomme4/11/)..dont know..the OP has to confirm.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tested your fiddle and it is working.  I modified the colors and tested again - and it worked again.  However, you images were broken links, so I could easily see the background color.  My guess is that your images are opaque and, therefore, you cannot see the color that is BEHIND them.

Your best bet is to create two images - one with normal color and one with black color.  Call the normal image "NormalImage.jpg" and call the black background one "NormalImage_black.jpg".  Then, onhover, replace ".jpg" with "_black.jpg" - and on mouseout, replace "_black.jpg" with ".jpg".  If you are having trouble doing this with css, try using Javacsript - and remember to load all images (but hide the backgorund ones) upon page_load, so that when someone hovers, the browser doens't have to load the image - it only needs to display it.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is I cannot use transparent PNG images because of the specific needs of the project. Are there any other solutions for the JPG images, just a simple color overlay on hover?

Comment: No, there isn't a simpler way to do it.  If you have an opaque image, it doesn't matter what's behind it - you won't see it.

You're not trying to change the color of the DOM behind the image - you're trying to change the color of the image, itself.  You cannot do that with javascript, alone - but you can make multiple copies of the image and change the src attribute when necessary (this is a common tool for hovering on buttons/nav-menus, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of what you want exactly. If you want a transparent background to cover the image.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/qg2s8eds/2/)

Other wise you would need to use transparent png's to change the white to black background on the image itself.

```
.img-responsive.products {
border: 1px solid black;
cursor: pointer;   
}

figcaption {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 20px;
background: #2c3f52;
color: #ed4e6e;
}
figcaption {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
color:#fff;
text-align: center;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}
.col-sm-3:hover figcaption {
opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hover effect is working as it is intended, the problem is the images are taking up the full area so you can't see any background effects. Try giving the images a `padding:20px;` to see the background changes. As mentioned above you will need to either create an image sprite or change the image to a transparent .png in order for the full background to change.
ex: http://jsfiddle.net/20oomme4/6/

Answer (score 0):

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/20oomme4/11/)

This is the same CSS that you used, ie.

```
.img-responsive.products:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Only thing is that i've used a png image with no background. And as you can see in the fiddle your code works correctly.

So, **As i mentioned in my comments, i would suggest you to use a png image without any background**.